# Improving the efficiency of searching a normalised logs table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, logging

For many years now I've recorded user interaction logs using PHP and MySQL in a normalised format such as this:

- LogID (int)
- UserID (int)
- TargetUserID (optional int)
- ActionID (int)
- AdditionalString1 (string)
- AdditionalString2 (string)

This would allow me to re-construct the logs using PHP afterwards to create logs like these:

- John Smith kicked Amy Adams from the server for 'spamming messages' (stored as "1,1,2,1,'spamming messages','')
- Amy Adams sent John Smith $300,000 for 'house payment' (stored as "2,2,1,2,'300000','house payment')

All whilst only storing a very small amount of data, as shown.

The problem is that in order to search this data, every log message has to be reconstructed before filtering. So if I have 500,000 log messages, I have to parse all 500,000 into the above format, in order to match a filter such as "Smith kicked" (which would match the first log) or "sent John" (which would match the second).

I know that I could store the log messages in full-text to begin with, but this worries me as then when users change name, or when log message formats change, these old messages would be stuck.

I can only assume there is a best practise for this, and I fear it might be to use an additional technology such as Logstash, but just wanted to see what people thought first.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have master tables for action names, user names (all the FKs in your log table) etc ? If yes, why not simply join them appropriately, and filter on the values there.

Comment: We have found that for logging and especially searching, MySQL is not the ideal tool. We log to ElasticSearch a combination of the full message and some individual fields. Searching the logs is very flexible. Scaling is easy. Cleaning up old logs is simple as could be. I'm a huge proponent of MySQL - it's just not the best tool for _this_ particular purpose, in my experience.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya currently all parsing is done in PHP and all log formats are stored in code. This is because the formatting is not standardised betwen logs. For example, one log may be written <User> <interaction> <TargetUser>, whilst the next may be <User> <Interaction> <AdditionalInfo1> <AdditionalInfo2>. Maybe this could be converted to MySQL, I'm not too sure... though I fear it would be a big undertaking

Comment: @Timo that's what I fear may be the outcome here... we do use ElasticSearch for some other stuff but this particular environment is lightweight and does not feature an ELK stack, so I'm hoping I can come up with a simpler solution but may have to fall back to this (the existing solution works fine with a small number of logs).

Comment: @DuncanMcArdle Can you elaborate on your searching requirements? Who wants to search, in what way, and why? That might help find a way without introducing additional infrastructure.

Comment: Fairly standard use case (I think) of administrators looking at logs of what users have been doing. An audit trail is important so ideally an administrator would be able to look years into the past. They might be looking for who carried out a specific action, what a specific user did, or who interacted with a given user, stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

There are several techniques how you can optimize your algorithm which needs to go through all the logs in order to systematically parse them.

One of the techniques you can use is caching partial results for expensive operations and reusing the cached results where possible. In your case caching results of database SELECT queries will mean you don't need to execute **the same SELECT queries** multiple times - in some cases it can be several hundreds / thousands / millions of times. This technique is also known as **[Memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)** and is a one of the techniques used in [dynamic programming](https://towardsdatascience.com/solving-problems-with-dynamic-programming-ea4a872dae61).